# Pra que server o expressjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express.js, single-page-application

Oque é, pra que serve e como funciona o express.js?
É indicado usar ele junto ao AngularJS em uma app SPA?

Comment: Olá André, bem vindo ao SOpt. Em sua pergunta você faz diversas perguntas, o que acaba deixando o assunto um pouco amplo. Eu sugeriria você a [edit] a sua pergunta e colocar alguma explicação. Se você realmente tem dúvidas sobre o que é o **Express.JS**, coloque o que "pensa" que é, que será de melhor ajuda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O Express.js é um framework Node que pode ser comparado com o Laravel para PHP, ele cria abstrações de rotas, middlewares e muitas outras funções para facilitar a criação tanto de API's quanto SPA's.

Um exemplo bacana de uso dele é a exposição de uma API simples de get que pode ser feita com poucos cliques em menos de 10 minutos.

Agora, não confunda Angular e Express, o Angular.js é uma biblioteca **front-end** enquanto o Express é um framework **Back-end**, ou seja, enquanto o angular está preocupado em facilitar a vida do programador no que diz respeito em tratamento e exibição de dados, o Express está voltado para a criação e obtenção dos dados a partir do seu servidor. Independente da linguagem que os irá utilizar.

Eu diria que eles são *complementares*, mas não iguais, nem podem ser comparados.

Sobre a sua segunda pergunta, não é só indicado como é muito recomendado utilizar Express.js com Angular.js, assim como qualquer outro framework ou biblioteca front-end (como o React.js ou o Polymer). Veja que o Express, como um framework Back-End, pode ser utilizado com qualquer linguagem que consuma seus dados.