# Dúvida: ExpressJS sem framework front-end?

Tags: express.js

Olá, boa tarde.

Eu pretendo estar iniciando meu projeto no NodeJS + ExpressJS, mas eu não conheço muito bem essa tecnologia. Muita gente falam que o Express serve apenas para desenvolvimento de API's e eventualmente integrar em um front-end ao estiver pronto.
Então minha dúvida é: É possível desenvolver aplicação sem usar nenhum framework front-end, apenas com o ExpressJS e um Handlebars ou Jade?

Comment: Sim, pode desenvolver uma aplicação com NodeJs + ExpressJS + Handlebars sem usar mais nenhuma framework adicional. [Mais informação sobre Express](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149296/pra-que-server-o-expressjs?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

É perfeitamente possível fazer uma aplicação em ExpressJS e servir conteúdo com alguma engine destas que vocês mencionou. Existem inclusive alguns tutoriais na própria página de documentação do Express, que podemos conferir [aqui](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Answer (score 0):

Claro! Eu mesmo, tento usar o mínimo de Bibliotecas/Frameworks, e até hoje nunca tive nenhum problema.
Os frameworks são para te ajudar a desenvolver Front End... Pense como não usar framework, fazer uma conta no papel, e usar frameWork, usando uma calculadora. Eles te ajudam a fazer a página, e gastar menos tempo fazendo, mas o resultado pode ser (quase) o mesmo em ambos os casos.